# Convert Nested object into custom array of objects: Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am having array of objects that look like this

```
const test = {
  a: { name: "A", selected: [1, 2, 3], display: [1, 2, 3] },
  b: { name: "B", selected: [4, 5, 6], display: [4, 5, 6] },
  c: { name: "C", selected: [7, 8, 9], display: [7, 8, 9] },
  d: { name: "D", selected: [], display: [] }
};
```

I want the above to be converted as below

```
const output = [
  { field: "A", selectedValues: [1, 2, 3] },
  { field: "B", selectedValues: [4, 5, 6] },
  { field: "C", selectedValues: [7, 8, 9] }
];
```

Basically key in the input object to be made as `field` in the final object of that array and `selected` in input object should be made as `selectedValues` in the final object. Note only the object that has some entries `selected` should be put into final arrray

Also when all the objects in the input object have `selected` as empty then just return empty array else return the above output.

Code that I tried

```
const result = Object.entries(test).map(([name, v]) => ({
  field: name,
  selectedValues: v
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Did you mean `selectedValues: v.selected`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you want

> selected in input object should be made as selectedValues in the final object.

you should navigate to the `.selected` property (the subarray) while mapping, instead of referencing the whole object. Afterwards, filter by whether that array has any values in it.

```js
const test = {
  a: { name: "A", selected: [1, 2, 3], display: [1, 2, 3] },
  b: { name: "B", selected: [4, 5, 6], display: [4, 5, 6] },
  c: { name: "C", selected: [7, 8, 9], display: [7, 8, 9] },
  d: { name: "D", selected: [], display: [] }
};


const result = Object.entries(test)
  .map(([name, obj]) => ({
    field: name,
    selectedValues: obj.selected
  }))
  .filter(({ selectedValues }) => selectedValues.length);

console.log(result);
```